# Android : Change the background color of a listview/gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, background-color

I'm trying to change the background of a selected item in a gridview, so I used the following code to do that

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    // Basically changes the boolean value of an object's variable to "true", this means it has been clicked on 
                    Themes.themes.get((int)id).clicked= true;

                    // Reload the list 
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Then in the `getview()` method of my adapter class I use

```
if(theme.clicked)
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
```

Once I click on a item of my gridview its background color changes, but when I scroll down the background color of other cells in the gridview also changes. I tired using different methods to apply the onclick event (like using a selector) but nothing seems to be working.

Does someone know of a way to solve this issue ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: One way would be put the color property in your adapter and then retrieve it, your views are recycling so thats why its happening

Comment: @lawonga As you said the recycling of the views is indeed the root of the problem. But the color property is in fact being handled in the adapter, my code checks the object's "clicked" attribute, if it's true it colors the view it's about to return in green, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Hm. is the property in the item in the arraylist as well? it shouldn't mess up if that is the case.

Comment: @lawonga The property is in each object of the arraylist. So yes it shouldn't have been messing up, but I've found the solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because of recycling of views. You need to set the background color for unselected items also.

```
if(theme.clicked)
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));

else {
       //Set the default color here for unselected items
}
```

Comment: Weird enough, this solvd my problem, this never would have dawned on me! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a background in the drawable folder name *selector_bg.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryPress"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

i supose you have a layout for the cellule of your gridView ?
if so set android:background="@drawable/selector_bg"

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I had in fact already tried this way but it didn't work, I just tried it again but still nothing. What happens in that the cell's color changes once I click, once the click is released the cell's color goes back to how it initially was.